# How do I click on button puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I never try this website but since I read this website forums provides helps from very much skilled engineers or other forum members so I'm here to seek help.

My problem is that I try to click the class name path which not works, so I rather would be to execute click in the element I want by clicking the object from margin-top randomly 40px to 80px

**My puppeteer code:**

```
await page.waitForSelector('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/svg', { timeout: 7000 });
await page.mouse.click(100, 100);
```

Comment: What does it mean it doesn't work? What result do you get? Any errors? You use xPath with `page.waitForSelector()` which won't work, you need to use `page.waitForXPath()` method https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options

Comment: @pavelsaman I want to click the xpath selector the svg play button: https://live.shopee.com.my/p/share?from=live&session=1231359&viewer=115#copy_link
thanks

Comment: So what results you have got with my little help? Have you looked into the Puppeteer dcumentation I also linked?

Comment: @pavelsaman it not click and I cant check live it is in docker so i dont see browser only can check the logs :(

Comment: @pavelsaman actually I found this in github docker script and I try to modify it works on my website, here snippet: https://textuploader.com/1875e